# Failed to verify code signature of ipa, which is only occurring some times, why is it not occurring every time

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

Failed to verify code signature of ipa, if i tried to install one app,
 i thought it could be either a certificate or provisioning profile issue but if i install another app this app is being installed without any error.
what could be the issue.?

Comment: Do you mean that it is failing to install if it is the only app installed on a device.  However, if you install another app signed with your provisioning profile first, then the app will work?  If so, most likely your code signing settings are wrong in the failing app, but right in the second app that causes the first to work.  Basically, when trying to run an app, it just needs any valid provisioning profile on the device in order to run, even if it was installed as part of another app.  So app 2 installs with a provisioning profile that works for app 1 and app 2.

Comment: Compare your code signing settings between the two apps and make sure you have the right code signing identity and profile.  Use the settings from the second app to build the first and see if it works, even when it is the only app installed on the device.

Comment: Both have same code signing identities and provisioning profiles

Comment: Take a look at the device console when you try to install it and it fails.  The error message will give insight into why it is failing.

Comment: Also, provisioning profiles are tied to app IDs.  You can use a wildcard app ID as long as you are not using certain features (iCloud, push notifications, etc.), but simply using the same profile and signing identity in two apps isn't a guarantee that your settings are correct.  The device console will give you the reason for the failure.